# Firebase StartAt() doesn't work - it returns the same results without it

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the first 5 results (1-5), and then (6-10)... and so on.
I save the last value I received, in order to StartAt where I stopped,
but when I check the new values it still shows values 1-5 and not 6-10.

Also, I don't understand if I really have to use orderByChild while my keys are already sorted on DB.

My DB-

```
users
    +user1
    +user2
    +user3
    +user4
    +user5
    +user6
    .....
    +user50
```

First 1-5:

```
  task = await FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").OrderByValue().LimitToFirst(5).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(t => t);
```

That works fine.
Now I'm trying to get users 6-10

```
  lastUserId= "user5"
  task=null;
  task = await FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").OrderByValue().StartAt(lastUserId).LimitToFirst(5).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(t => t);
  DataSnapshot dts = task.Result;
  foreach (DataSnapshot s in dts.Children)
  {
  Debug.Log(s.Key);
  }
```

output:
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
Why does it start from user1 if my code says StartAt("user5")?? What am I missing?

Comment: You should be using OrderByKey.StartAt('userId')

Comment: Yes. Write it as an answer

Comment: I added it as an answer. Please mark it as accepted. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, here is my (very short) answer:

You should use `OrderByKey.StartAt('userId')` rather than `OrderByValue`.

Glad I could help.